# THREE js glTF loader unsupported

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Пытаюсь использовать GLTFLoader в Three js для загрузки стартовой отрисовки объекта, но получаю ошибку о том, моя версия glTf не поддерживается, и нужно использовать версию 2.0. Вроде делаю все по доке но получаю такую ошибку в консоли (см. скрин). Вот код как я импортирую загрузчик в файле с кодом.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Canvas, useUpdate } from 'react-three-fiber';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

export default class Hand {
  constructor() {}

  handInit() {
    let scene = new THREE.Scene();
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      100,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    let handContainer: any = document.getElementById('hand-container');
    handContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera.position.z = 20;

    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    loader.load(
      './adapters/glove/new_hand.json',
      function (gltf) {
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
      },
      undefined,
      function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );

    const render = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    render();
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: а расширение не gltf.. попробуйте открыть  модель еще где то, например тут https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com

Comment: О спасибо большое!